# Goland remote debug

Tags: ssh, sftp, remote-debugging, goland

I'm using Goland (on Windows (host) and Ubuntu (install in local VMware)) and trying to remote debug to Ubuntu desktop, I have customized SFTP to automatically update the changed file in Ubuntu. But remote debug config show error

[image]

How to fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This scenario is not currently, as of 2021.1, supported.

Watch this issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/GO-10609 to see when this will be fixed.